# Dataset not populating even after providing parameters for creating rdlc report. Resturn empty table with only column headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, report, rdlc

I have debugged the whole process, the parameters are provided correctly and are authentic to the dataset but in return there is no result. The table is empty. Whereas when i run the query manually in sqlserver it return the result. The reportviewer does not show any error it just shows the column headers.

**aspx Code:**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Width="100%" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="CABDataSetTableAdapters.JobsTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CABDataSet dsUsersInfo = new CABDataSet();

    var da = new JobsTableAdapter();

    da.GetData(Convert.ToDateTime(_txtFrom.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(_txtTo.Text));

    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report1.rdlc");

    ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsUsersInfo.Tables[0]);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to ensure dsUsersInfo.Tables[0] is having data you want to display, and then try calling the ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh() function

Comment: dsUsersInfo.Tables[0] is having empty table. the same query when i try in sqlserver it works.

Comment: if the data table is empty, seems like da.GetData(...) function do not fill the datatable, you may need to check on it.